# Another "why was my answer deleted" looking for advice to be better

Tags: discussion, answers

I am new to posting questions and answers on SE, although not new to using the various SE resources. I also get the need for questions and answers to be concise and accurate, we all need answers and quickly.

Purely to give me some direction for future answers what specifically was the reason to delete my answer to this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/773568/why-is-network-manager-still-so-bad/773577#773577

The question was more of an opinion, but I only had so much to go on and as I have spent stacks of time getting various Wi-Fi nics working on Ubuntu and debian I felt I could help but it would need some info and guidance rather than a specific x+y answer. Maybe that was it?

Answer (score 19):

It was flagged and subsequently deleted for not being "an answer". I think that was fair. It was clear you were only trying to be helpful but what was posted would have been better suited as a comment.

<sup>I know, I know. You **can't** post comments yet.</sup>

The answer section really is (with very mild exceptions) for posts that attempt to fix the problem directly. Or that both ask questions and pre-empt them with solutions. That sort of thing. We tidy away anything that doesn't fit into that groove.

Additionally the question wasn't great so that's been closed since too.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand it's a mix of need to be objective but will naturally be a bit subjective. I'll stick to clear questions and direct answers.

Answer (score 4):

> Purely to give me some direction for future answers what specifically was the reason to delete my answer to this question: Why is network-manager still so bad?

I don't know why your answer was deleted, but I will tell you that **you shouldn't answer this kind of questions**. In the end, your answer would end up deleted anyways, since closed questions are eligible for deletion. So, why was your answer deleted? It would endup deleted anyways, so I wouldn't worry about that. Try to answer better questions instead and you wouldn't worry about getting your answers deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I know sometimes I post quickly and my grammar isn't perfect but some of your edits left my sentence not making sense. I can't edit yours but I would like to, I only answered one question, not 'questions'. The question was closed after my answer. endup is not one word nor is anyways and I wasn't worried just wanted some advice. Please take this a bit tongue in cheek, but it's getting a bit much if we have edits occuring this much, maybe we should all just trying and answers questions anyways and not endups getting picky about grammar :)

Comment: @Jools I'm not criticizing your grammar, nor your orthography, my point is that you should avoid answering these questions at all costs. These questions tend to gather bad answers, which in turn drops the quality of the site. That's why we close them.