# Is it possible to control font size?

Tags: support, text-formatting

Can I make some text larger or smaller?

btw I noticed an answer [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15405/174392) (by Oli), there's a line where the text seems smaller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about per-text size changes, there's some basic things you can do.

For large text, you can use a `#` before the text.

`#Hello_World` goes to

## Hello_World

It needs to be on its own line.

The small text you see in Oli's answer was produced by putting `<sup></sup>` or `<sub></sub>` around the text.

```
<sup>I know, I know. You **can't** post comments yet.</sup>
```

to

<sup>I know, I know. You **can't** post comments yet.</sup>

I don't know if there are other text size options, but according to [this Meta SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170480/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-size-in-the-code-markdown), there don't seem to be any more options.

Edit:

Thanks to Videonauth, I can now say that using some basic HTML tags will work, such as `<h1></h1>`, `h2`, etc. I think these will display differently on different browsers, depending on whether or not AU/SE has them customized in the CSS.

Comment: There is `*word*` for *italics* and `**word**` for **bold**

Comment: @Videonauth that's not really font size

Comment: Well the most common `html` works too i think so `<h1></h1>` till `<h6></h6>` but don't nail me down on that I'm mostly fine with the given board options.

Comment: @Videonauth they do!

Comment: Using more "#"'s will change the size of text (downward only though).